# Customizing UIPickerView in xcode

Tags: height, uipickerview, customizing

I developed an application which consists of UIPickerView....It displays as default size in height of the UIPickerView.I want to display the UIPickerView as 320x480 size(iphone simulator size)..so the whole screen has the picker view without using transorm property,because it will stretched the whole view....its not looking good...even with selection indicator also stretched...I need not stretchable picker view..but need to show the picker view with the whole screen..We can control the width of the UIPickerView..But how can we control the height of the UIPickerView.....

Thanks & Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently with sdk 3.0 you can call setFrame: or initWithFrame: on the UIPickerView to make it any size you like.  Would that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for replying to my problem.Now it is coming with the exact dimensions which i want(initWithFrame: is not effecting the pickerView, I used setFrame: to the pickerView, the problem was solved..)But the pickerView has the black color below the selection indicator and above the selection indicator shows as clear color(as it default picker view) and also the looking of pickerview is not good as what we have default.I didnt give any backgroundColor for the pickerview,eventhough it is coming with the black color as background below the indicator,Could you suggest me where the problem is..

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say, but I'm pretty sure that you cannot adjust the UIPickerView.  There are a few hacks you might be able to perform to achieve the results you are looking for as well as changing the color, transparency, etc., but I'm pretty sure that there are not part of the public API and that your app will not be approved.

Good luck.